# git adding existing project to repo

Tags: git

I have installed git server (private server) using

http://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/installsetup-and-configure-git-server-with-gitolite-and-gitweb-on-centosrhel-6-4/

as per instructions I can create a repo, which is fine.
My projects resides in `/var/www/html/`

How can I create a repo, which user can download, work and when push, it gets updated to `/var/www/html/prj1/` folder.

Kindly let me know, thanks

Comment: I have put a simple article on this. I hope it helps.
http://www.zeshan.info/add-existing-project-to-git-repository/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for the `gitolite.conf` file:

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/conf.html

You'll want to create something like:

```
repo prj1
    RW+    .+    @all
```

Have you cloned the gitolite-admin repository from your git server yet? Do that. That's where you can edit gitolite.conf, commit then push the change. As soon as you push, Gitolite reads the config file and will create any new repositories you've added in the config file, and it will remove repositories you no longer reference.

Then to clone:

```
git clone git@gitolite-server:prj1
```

And then it's a normal `git pull` or `git push` after that.

Comment: I have done this steps and it works fine. The repo are stored in /home/git/repositries. When user does the push, i want /var/www/html/prj1 folder also to update for testing purpose. how can i do this? thank you for your answer

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the question you are asking. Basically you want updates to repo A to be reflected in repo B for say, an automated build for continuous integration, or so QA can pull in those changes and perform testing?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I want to setup gerrit as well. But before hand, i also need to make the php pages available in /var/www/html/prj1 directory, so that i can test.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create bare repository if its a production server.

Create a bare repository some where on your server and points that to your existing project. There is a nice article written on it, please navigate to that for more details. Link is http://www.zeshan.info/add-existing-project-to-git-repository/